# How to handle error in readline nodej module

Tags: node.js, readline

I have a simple script reading file one by line.

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const readline = require('node:readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('file-with-a-extremly-long-strings'),
  crlfDelay: Infinity,
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
});
```

It works ok if all lines in file is small with not a huge length,
But if I pass a file with long lines in it I got an error:

```
node:readline:649
    string = this._line_buffer + string;
                               ^

RangeError: Invalid string length
    at Interface._normalWrite (node:readline:649:32)
    at ReadStream.ondata (node:readline:269:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at node:internal/fs/streams:275:14
    at FSReqCallback.wrapper [as oncomplete] (node:fs:660:5)
```

How to catch this exception? I wasn't able to find a way.

Also there is no `error` event in readline what is very strange to me.

I've tried almost everything I was able to find in google and docs. But there is only catch for file not exist for `createReadStream`

UPD: Only way I found how to catch this error is `process.on('unaughtException', ....`:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.error('Error:', err);
});
```